# Can I run Amazon Kinesis Analytics (KDA) using Amazon EventBridge rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, aws-event-bridge, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I need to run a KDA application using an EventBridge rule? is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think EventBridge [targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html) can be KDA app, however you can send the events to a kinesis stream and have your app read off the stream.

Comment: yep. EventBridge can't target KDA. as a resolution set EventBridge rule to run a Lambda and trigger KDA through lambda